# How to get django-debug-toolbar style exception information for scripts?

Tags: python, django, debugging

The `django-debug-toolbar` is, as many know, wonderful for debugging Django requests -- on an exception it shows an interactive stack trace with local variables and other information.

Is it possible to get similar information to show when hitting an exception while running a Django script, i.e. via the django-extensions `runscript` management command?